# Open data viewer and script file at same time in different panes

Tags: rstudio

While writing analysis code in a script file, I open and check the data file from time to time. I appears that both data and script have to be in the same pane. It would be convenient to have both files open simultaneously in different panes. Is there a way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can open a new 'source windows'.

- drag your Source viewer (data or script) outside your Rstudio window. It will open as a new screen.
- Click on the "Show in New Window button", next to the Filter button. It will do the same.

This way you can see your scripts & data alongside. Or multiple data/scripts alongside

( see the Rstudio support on Using Source Windows)